# Change RichEdit text colour independently with text already loaded

Tags: delphi, colors, richedit

How can I change the text color of a Rich Edit line by line? It is dependent on the position. First line must be red, second green and so forth. The problem is the text of the Rich Edit is already loaded in. So it must be changed after the text is already in the control. I am using Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to load it with the right colours from the beginning.

But to answer your question, a quick and dirty and rather ugly solution is to do

```
function RandomColor: TColor;
begin
  Result := RGB(Random(256), Random(256), Random(256))
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to RichEdit1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    RichEdit1.CaretPos := Point(0, i);
    RichEdit1.SelLength := RichEdit1.Lines[i].Length;
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := RandomColor;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note, you can use the `EM_EXSETSEL` message to set the selection's start and end at the same time (`CaretPos` does this internally, setting the start and end to the same value). Also, you should use the `EM_LINELENGTH` message instead of `RichEdit1.Lines[i].Length`. Also, you should use the `EM_SETEVENTMASK` message to disable `EN_SELCHANGE` notifications (firing the `TRichEdit.OnSelectionChange` event) while manipulating the selection. And then wrap the whole code in `WM_SETREDRAW` to disable screen updates while changing the colors.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I know. That's why I emphasised that the solution is "quick and dirty and rather ugly". (And I didn't have the time to study the details of the RichEdit API. In many practical situations, this solution is good enough, though.) Feel free to post an improved version as an answer and I'll delete this one.

Comment: See [Faster rich edit syntax highlighting](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm)

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that page. But using a RIch Edit control as a syntax-highlighting programmer's editor isn't ideal, is it, even if it is possible? :)

Comment: No, a RichEdit is not the ideal choice for a syntax highlighting editor.  But for a simple line-based logger, it will suffice. And that has to solve similar issues that a syntax highlighter has to solve when dealing with coloring after inserting the text.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the richedit control is not divided into lines, but rather wordwrapped on the fly depending on the size of the control (perhaps changing on form resize), then you can use this procedure to colour lines alternatingly between red, green, blue:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  ColorWheel: array[0..2] of TColor = (clRed, clGreen, clBlue);
var
  RowNr, RowStartPos, RowEndPos, C: Integer;
  HasReachedEnd: Boolean;
begin
  HasReachedEnd := False;
  RowStartPos := 0;
  C := 0;
  RowNr := 1;
  repeat
    RowEndPos := RichEdit1.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, RowNr, 0);
    if RowEndPos = -1 then
    begin
      // Last row reached
      HasReachedEnd := True;
      RowEndPos := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
    end;
    // Select text
    RichEdit1.SelStart := RowStartPos;
    RichEdit1.SelLength := RowEndPos - RowStartPos;
    // Change selected text colour
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := ColorWheel[C];
    C := (C + 1) mod 3;
    // Prepare for next row
    RowStartPos := RowEndPos;
    Inc(RowNr);
  until HasReachedEnd;
end;
```

Comment: You should use `RichEdit1.GetTextLen()` instead of `Length(RichEdit1.Lines.Text)`

Comment: Ah, indeed! I edit my answer to incorporate your correct suggestion.